# php listing category

Tags: php, mysql

I have a email booking form whit 3 type of category's, and in each of theme there is 3

packages to select, when i select a category in my select list menu, should appear in the bottom

the other select list menu with his related packages of the category.

What is the best way to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either store the related packages in a data structure that you can lookup on demand in javascript, this way when you switch the first drop down box, you can use the onchange to call a method that updates the contents of the second.

Or use an ajax query to get the information for a particular category and populate when onchange is called.

I would prefer the first method for small lists that are not going to change often, if the list is likely to change though dynamically (based on a database for example) and/or there are large quantities of categories/packages then I would go with the ajax approach.

Comment: +1. Third alternative: if they're just nine items, you may as well group them and put them in one Select box all together. While it's not necessarily an answer to your question, it's probably the easiest thing to get done.

Comment: Its true if the packages are obvious to the user which category they are from (if this is important).  However lets say the category were Ford Mondeo, VW Pasatt etc and the packages was actually colours or something.  Then you would either have a confusing box with just colours and not know which car it related to, or you would have a list box with multiple pasattas, multiple mondeos etc depending on the number of colours.

Comment: No, completely right. Implied part of my suggestion was to write the categories in the descriptions as well. :-) (Well, by 'implied' I really mean 'incidentally omitted')